# facebook sdk android wall post line break

Tags: android, facebook

I'm making an application that is posting some information to your facebook wall using facebook sdk for android. This works, but I can't seem to get new lines on the posts. I have tried `\n` but it doesent work. Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();

String temp = "";
for (int i = 0; i < mArrayAdapter.getCount(); i++){
            temp = temp + mArrayAdapter.getItem(i) + "\n"; // Not working
}

parameters.putString("message", temp);
mFacebook.dialog(this, "stream.publish", parameters, new DialogListener());
```

Thanks,

James Ford

Answer (score 1):

Hi James i have tried that before, even with html code but i think thats not possible.
The reason, Facebook must have a control to avoid blank spaces or line break on his posts.

Answer (score 1):

New lines are not allowed in stream posts (the fact that you may have seen them in the past are bugs on facebook).

Comment: Seems true. But what I can do is make new lines with alt+enter when typing to a wall. Maybe you can do something with this?

Answer (score 0):

make use of JSON to post on facebook..
 how? [look here](http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2011/01/26/using-json-in-android/)

STEPS :-

Step 1 :- At this link u will came to know how to use JSON for setting text to TEXTVIEW.

Step 2 :- May be this is not u r looking for :)  assign the text of textview to some string 
          using `GetText().ToString`

Step 3 :- use this string to post to the facebook.

Step 4 :- I did the same after spending lot of time in googling and finally got the result
          by using this trick. u can see my post that i posted during test [here](https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=417074284975256&id=100000180652750&ref=notif&notif_t=feed_comment)

Step 5 :- set the visibilty of this text box to gone using

```
tv.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

And u r done with your posting to facebook.. 
let the facebook and textview handle how they manage spaces and new line character :D

Some Coding work for newbies like me...

I am posting it on click of button

1)

```
 tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
 click=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    click.setOnClickListener(mthdpost);
```

2)   add on click event to this button

```
   private View.OnClickListener mthdpost=new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
try {
                String json = "{"

                    + "  \"name\": \"myName\", "

                    + "  \"message\": [\"myMessage1\",\"myMessage2\"],"

                    + "  \"place\": \"myPlace\", "

                    + "  \"date\": \"thisDate\" "

                    + "}";

                /* Create a JSON object and parse the required values */

                JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(json).nextValue();

                String name = object.getString("name");

                String place = object.getString("place");

                String date = object.getString("date");

                JSONArray message = object.getJSONArray("message");

                String MessageToPost= null;
                tv.setText("Name: "+ name +"\n\n");

                tv.append("Place: "+ place +"\n\n");

                tv.append("Date: "+ date +"\n\n");



                /*JSONObject attachment = new JSONObject();

                attachment.put("Name: ","\n\n");

                attachment.put("Place: ","\n\n");

                attachment.put("Date: ","\n\n");*/

                for(int i=0;i<message.length();i++)

                {

                    tv.append("Message: "+ message.getString(i) +"\n\n");
                    //attachment.put("Message: ","\n\n");

                }
                MessageToPost=tv.getText().toString();
                postToWall(MessageToPost);// called the method having logic to post on wall and sending the textview text to to post as message

                } catch (JSONException e)
                {e.printStackTrace();
                }

                catch(Exception ex)
                {ex.printStackTrace();}

                }


        };
```

3)  method for posting the message

```
public void postToWall(String msg){


        Log.d("Tests", "Testing graph API wall post");
        try {
               String response = facebook.request("me");
               Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
               //parameters.putString("message", msg.toString());
               parameters.putString("message", msg);
               parameters.putString("description", "test test test");
               response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, 
                       "POST");
               Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
               if (response == null || response.equals("") || 
                       response.equals("false")) {
                  Log.v("Error", "Blank response");
               }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
```

### HOPE IT WILL HELP :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
StringBuilder messageData = new StringBuilder(title).append('\n')
    .append('\n').append(message).append('\n').append('\n')
    .append(description);
// Message
postParams.putString("message", messageData.toString());
```

Answer (score -1):

This works:

Use this: `<center></center>`

Instead of a br or a newline, etc. You can only do one in a row (ie. you can't increase the spacing).

Comment: This does the trick but, as stated, does not make for new lines.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it "does the trick" and then "does not make for new lines"?  It _does_ allow you to start on a new line (albeit not two lines consecutively).

Comment: Well, a typical new line character code can be repeated multiple times.  The "center" tag tricks the renderer into ending a line since the character justification changes.  So, you can use it for terminating a line, but this will not result in the empty line between paragraphs which is pretty much a requirement for readable text.

Comment: lol... but it DOES result in a new line though; right?  Just not more than one in a row (i.e. vertical spacing).  Strictly speaking my answer works.

Comment: It will break the line, yes, so you can have text start on another line. I can't say what the renderer is doing, can you? Basically it appears to me to confuse the renderer

Comment: Yes I can say.  The renderer is starting the text that comes after it on a new line.  That's why they call it a "New Line".  Yes, it's a trick - and maybe Facebook will change and "fix" it so it doesn't work any more - but for now and for some time now using <center></center> to create a new line has worked and my solution is inelegant, to be sure, but it IS a solution.

Comment: New Line or "newline" is a programming term that has been around for a long time. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: The questioner did not ask how to produce "New Line" or a "newline" character.  The questioner simply asked: "I can't seem to get new lines on the posts".  My solution works.  Period.